# Value of list changing inside for loop while using stream

Tags: java, java-stream

```
Set<String> l = locMap.keySet();
for (Map.Entry<String, String> ven : venderAndFactoryLocMap.entrySet()) {
  if (ven.getValue().equals(VENDOR)) {
    Map<String, String> x1 = l.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> x + "-" + ven.getKey(), x -> PROCESS));
    locMap.putAll(x1);
  }
}
```

In the above , the value of locMap keeps changing but also the value of L (which is the hashset) also changes, I was in the view that once we have assigned a variable its value will not be changed in the stack , why this is happening ?

I was expecting that the Set remains constant , while we are changing the locMap

Comment: Not sure, if you want the philosophy or the concret fact, but the method KeySet() returns the actual Set inside your Map and not a clone of it. https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk8u/blob/master/jdk/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java

Answer (score 3):

It is changed, due to implementation of `keySet()`. From the javadoc of `HashMap#keySet`:

> Returns a Set view of the keys contained in this map. The set is
> backed by the map, so changes to the map are reflected in the set, and
> vice-versa.

To keep the value unchanged, you need to create a new set based on the keyset of locMap:

```
Set<String> l = new HashSet<>(locMap.keySet());
```

Comment: Or the immutable `Set.copyOf(locMap.keySet())` if you know there are no null keys in your map.